# Remove # symbol from the url in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I am facing issues with the  "#" symbol. I want to remove the # from the URL of my angular js website. I try to remove it with the help of "link provided" but it is not working and the site doesn't show anything. Please let me know how to make it possible. How to remove the # symbol from the URL.

Here is my code for route.js:-

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl: 'Templates/home.html',
    })
    .when("/first", {
        templateUrl: 'Templates/first.html',
    })
    .when("/second", {
        templateUrl: 'Templates/second.html',
    })
    .when("/third", {
        templateUrl: 'Templates/third.html',
    })
    .when("/admin", {
        templateUrl: 'Templates/admin.html',
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
```

Comment: What you tried to remove `#`. Explain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$locationProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider)

```
 var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
    app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: 'Templates/home.html',
        })
        .when("/first", {
            templateUrl: 'Templates/first.html',
        })
        .when("/second", {
            templateUrl: 'Templates/second.html',
        })
        .when("/third", {
            templateUrl: 'Templates/third.html',
        })
        .when("/admin", {
            templateUrl: 'Templates/admin.html',
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
             $locationProvider.html5Mode({
          enabled: true,
          requireBase: false
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

use the HTML5 History API

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Alternatively, you can use the base tag in your index.html (I suppose this is your landing page)

```
<head>
  <base href="/">
</head>
```

More details, please visit : https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

Comment: It is not working for me. I tried it before I write it here. I am new to Angular js so I do not know where I am going wrong..!!

Answer (score 0):

try this in your app.js

```
    var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config('$routerProvider', '$locationProvider',function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('*');

    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl: 'Templates/home.html',
    })
    .when("/first", {
        templateUrl: 'Templates/first.html',
    })
    .when("/second", {
        templateUrl: 'Templates/second.html',
    })
    .when("/third", {
        templateUrl: 'Templates/third.html',
    })
    .when("/admin", {
        templateUrl: 'Templates/admin.html',
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
```

**and add this base tag in your index.html file in head section**

```
<head>
   <base href="/">
</head>
```

Comment: not working for me you can explain in detail?? i did the same as mentioned above but didn't worked..!!